# Open a html at a specific anchor using Java

Tags: java, html, uri

I'm trying to make my JAVA software opens its documentation file (.html) when an user click on a button, but at a specific anchor depending on the button clicked, for a better guidance for the users.

For that, I have in the documentation file **a** tags, for example

```
<a name="Computations">
```

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public static void displayHelp(String HelpID){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("file:///");
    sb.append("C:/.../userManual.html");
    sb.append("#");//or \u0023
    sb.append(HelpID);
    try {
        URI uri = new URI(sb.toString());
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayHelp("Computations");
}
```

Launching this snippet will open the default browser, as intended, but at the beginning of the documentation file, which is strange since that if you take the same StringBuilder content (*file:///C:/.../userManual.html#Computations*) and search it in the default browser, it opens the documentation file at the specified anchor.

Further investigation on the URI class shows the constructor is parsing the String I give him, and consider the part after the # (*Computations*) as its *fragment*, hence not displaying this part on the research bar when launching the main.

Did I miss something on the URI class, which would allow me to do what I'm intending ?

If not, is there a workaround to this, which does not include JavaHelp, since I need to do a search in my file ?